# select sum ignoring group by

Tags: mysql, select, group-by, sum

Can't seem to get my query tweaked just right; any help would be appreciated.

Here's my query:

```
SELECT 
  wordlist.Word,
  SUM( worddocfreq.Freq ) AS wordFreq
FROM sourceparsed
  LEFT JOIN worddocfreq ON sourceparsed.ParsedID = worddocfreq.ParsedID
  LEFT JOIN wordlist ON worddocfreq.WordID = wordlist.WordID
WHERE
  sourceparsed.SrcID = 30032
GROUP BY
  wordlist.Word
```

This works as expected, and as example result set I get two columns: the first is a list of distinct words, and the second is the frequency of each word.

However, I would rather adjust the query so that the second column is instead a proportion (i.e. sum of the number of occurences of each word divided by the total number of words). The total number of words would be given by the sum of the second column, as it is output from the query as it is written above.

So, my problem is that I'm not sure how to compute the sum of the total number of words, because the 'group by' at the end of the query retrospectively imposes that the sum is computed for each word. So, I don't know how to divide my 2nd column by the sum calculated irrespective of the 'group by' term.

I have a feeling a nested select is required, but I'm not sure how to integrate this optimally.

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Cheers,

Brian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not certain it's the most efficient method, but give this a shot:

```
SELECT 
  wordlist.Word,
  SUM( worddocfreq.Freq ) / ( SELECT SUM( Freq ) 
                              FROM worddocfreq 
                                JOIN sourceparsed ON 
                                      sourceparsed.SrcID = sp1.SrcID
                                  AND sourceparsed.ParsedID = worddocfreq.ParsedID
                            ) AS proportion
FROM sourceparsed sp1
  LEFT JOIN worddocfreq ON sourceparsed.ParsedID = worddocfreq.ParsedID
  LEFT JOIN wordlist ON worddocfreq.WordID = wordlist.WordID
WHERE
  sourceparsed.SrcID = 30032
GROUP BY
  wordlist.Word
```

Comment: Thanks, but its not quite there. The portion "( SELECT SUM( Freq ) FROM worddocfreq )" gets the sum across every row of the worddocfreq table. I still need the 'grand sum' to be computed from rows that only match ParsedID in the sourceparsed table, where SrcID is 30032 in the sourceparsed table... in other words, this ignores the join when summing the 'grand sum'

Comment: OK, I see.  I added a JOIN to the inner SELECT - does that help?

Comment: pretty close, but the final working syntax I worked out is included in the edited version of my OP

Answer (score 0):

A `CROSS JOIN` to the subquery may (or may not) be more efficient than SetFreeByTruth's approach:

```
SELECT 
  wordlist.Word,
  SUM( worddocfreq.Freq ) / TotalFreq.TotalFreq AS wordFreq
FROM sourceparsed
  LEFT JOIN worddocfreq ON sourceparsed.ParsedID = worddocfreq.ParsedID
  LEFT JOIN wordlist ON worddocfreq.WordID = wordlist.WordID
  CROSS JOIN ( SELECT SUM( Freq ) AS TotalFreq FROM worddocfreq ) AS TotalFreq
WHERE
  sourceparsed.SrcID = 30032
GROUP BY
  wordlist.Word
```

Answer (score 0):

Be wary of divided by zero error. There could be a better approach but you can try the following:

```
select c,wordFreq,sum_all, wordFreq/sum_all as proportion from 
(

    (

        select wordlist.Word,
        sum(worddocfreq.Freq) as wordFreq
        from sourceparsed
        left join worddocfreq on sourceparsed.ParsedID = worddocfreq.ParsedID
        left join wordlist on worddocfreq.WordID = wordlist.WordID
        where sourceparsed.SrcID = 30032
        group by wordlist.Word

    ) c
   LEFT OUTER JOIN
   (select SUM(worddocfreq.Freq) sum_all  
    from sourceparsed
    left join worddocfreq on sourceparsed.ParsedID = worddocfreq.ParsedID
    left join wordlist on worddocfreq.WordID = wordlist.WordID 
    where sourceparsed.SrcID = 30032
   ) t
   ON 1=1
)
```